# ASP.NET Core - Creating View with select from database based on existing model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have standards views generated with scaffolding my model from `Main` table.

Now instead of standard `Details` view which shows details of single record based on `Main table` I want to show list (like in `Index` view) of all rows where this `id` appears in another table (called `Audit table`).

So when user clicks `Details` in `Index` view of Main table (model) it should get list of records from Audit table where that id appears.

**Main table model:**

```
 public partial class Main
    {
        public int id{ get; set; }
        public int SocID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
    }
```

**Audit table model:**

```
 public partial class Audit
    {
        public int idAudit{ get; set; }
        public int id{ get; set; }
        public int SocID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string DateOfChange { get; set; }
        public string Operation { get; set; }
    }
```

So I've modified `Details` class in my Main model Controller to return all records from Audit table based on `id` from Main table in following way:

```
public IActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var Audit = (from c in _context.Audit
                                where c.id == id
                                select new Audit
                                {
                                    SocID = c.SocID,
                                    Name = c.Name,
                                    Title = c.Title,                         
                                    User = c.User,
                                    DateOfChange = c.DateOfChange,
                                    Operation = c.Operation
                                }).ToList();
            if (Audit == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(Audit);
        }
```

And my View for Details class looks like this now:

```
@model IEnumerable<Audit>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Audit ....";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="table-responsive tableFixHead">

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover mx-auto w-auto" id="nkz10table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SocID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfChange)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Operation)
                </th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SocID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfChange)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Operation)
                    </td>
            
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

In Index view I'm calling Details with:

```
@model  IEnumerable<Audit>
....

<a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.id">Details</a>
```

when I click `Details` for specific id which has several records in `Audit` table I get

> 404 - page not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the 404 error comes from? the checking on `id` field or the checking on `Audit`? If you did get the expected value of `id`, then you can checking if `where c.id == id` is the statement you expect.

Comment: @Bemn id exists in Audit table and Main as well. Link in View on Details contains /id so why 404 - I don't know.

Comment: Where is the details link being generated? I do not see it. that will generally indicate where the issue is. As well, the controller that is serving the Index page

Comment: @Marcus controller serving Index works without problem, and so does Edit and Delete view. I've edited answer to see how I'm calling Details. Could be problem with the fact that I'm  using Audit model in Details and not Main table model. But I'm passing id which is id of main table as caling argument to controller which is working with Audit model.

Comment: it's not finding the path to Details action method. Issue with routing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with definition of controller, here is what worked for me in the end:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var audit= _context.audit
                .Where(m => m.Nkz10Pk == id);
            if (audit== null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(audit);
        }
```